# Installing dolphin on Retro Pie on raspberry pi 3 on Debian

Tags: retropie, games

I've installed Retro Pie and I would like add a Wii/GameCube emulator called dolphin so I can play Super Paper Mario. I know the internet has said that it's too slow IDK. I've installed a version from Github and I would Like to Build it. But after running :

```
cmake .. -DLINUX_LOCAL_DEV=true -DENABLE_GENERIC=1
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
-- Detected architecture: armv7l
-- Warning! Building generic build!
-- X11 support enabled
-- Xrandr found
--  Found avcodec: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so
--  Found avdevice: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavdevice.so
--  Found avfilter: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavfilter.so
--  Found avformat: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavformat.so
--  Found avutil: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavutil.so
--  Found swresample: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libswresample.so
--  Found swscale: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libswscale.so
-- libav/ffmpeg found, enabling AVI frame dumps
-- libevdev/libudev found, enabling evdev controller backend
-- Using named pipes as controller inputs
-- Watching game memory for changes
-- Enabling analytics collection (subject to end-user opt-in)
-- Could NOT find pugixml (missing:  pugixml_LIBRARIES pugixml_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Using static pugixml from Externals
-- Using static enet from Externals
-- Using static xxhash from Externals
-- Using shared zlib
-- Using static lzo from Externals
-- Using shared libpng
-- Using shared LibUSB
-- Could NOT find SFML (missing:  SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
-- Using static SFML 2.1 from Externals
-- Could NOT find MINIUPNPC (missing:  MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_DIR MINIUPNPC_LIBRARY MINIUPNPC_API_VERSION) 
-- Using static miniupnpc from Externals
-- Could NOT find MBEDTLS (missing:  MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR MBEDTLS_LIBRARY MBEDX509_LIBRARY MBEDCRYPTO_LIBRARY MBEDTLS_VERSION_OK) 
-- Using static mbed TLS from Externals
-- Using shared libcurl
-- Could NOT find HIDAPI (missing:  HIDAPI_LIBRARY HIDAPI_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Using static HIDAPI from Externals
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets: Found unsuitable version "3.0.2", but required is at least "3.1.0" (found -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf;-pthread;;;-lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0;-lwx_gtk2u_aui-3.0;-lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0;-lwx_baseu-3.0)
-- Using static wxWidgets from Externals
CMake Error at Externals/wxWidgets3/CMakeLists.txt:861 (message):
  wxGTK2 needs Xinerama and Xxf86vm


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/dolphin-master/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/dolphin-master/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

[image]

Comment: How did you download dolphin from github? It looks like the error you're getting is expecting you to be an a git repository, created automatically using "git clone https://github.com/someuser/projecturl.git"

Comment: I forgot where I got it. But I don't think that is really the issue. I may try re-downloading it from `https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin.git`

Answer (score 1):

The critical line appears to be:

```
wxGTK2 needs Xinerama and Xxf86vm
```

You will need to install Xinerama and Xxf86vm. Particularly, you'll need the development headers for these pacakges. You can use packages.debian.org to find them; just searching with the package names finds the following packages that you'll need to install:

- [`libxxf86vm-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libxxf86vm-dev)
- [`x11proto-xinerama-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/x11proto-xinerama-dev)

You can try installing those packages with:

sudo apt install libxxf86vm-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev

Then rerunning CMake. This should resolve the error.

Comment: Nope same error:                                                                                    
       ```Could NOT find wxWidgets: Found unsuitable version "3.0.2", but required is at least "3.1.0" (found -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf;-pthread;;;-lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0;-lwx_gtk2u_aui-3.0;-lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0;-lwx_baseu-3.0)
-- Using static wxWidgets from Externals
CMake Error at Externals/wxWidgets3/CMakeLists.txt:861 (message):
  wxGTK2 needs Xinerama and Xxf86vm```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and went looking for dependencies of `wxwidgets3`. Following the prerequisites [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started#Prerequisites) worked for me. Specifically, I ran `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev`. Then CMake finished and I was able to start compiling the Ishiiruka fork of Dolphin with `make`.